# How to run parallel thread groups on various slave nodes using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed-testing

I have 3 thread groups in my test plan and I have 3 slave nodes (remote servers). I would like to run all these thread groups in parallel but each one on a specific slave node.

```
+ Test Plan 
   + Thread Group A - (192.168.1.1)
       - HTTP Request Defaults
       - Cookie Manager
       + HTTP Request X
   + Thread Group B - (192.168.1.2)
       - HTTP Request Defaults
       - Cookie Manager
       + HTTP Request Y
   + Thread Group C - (192.168.1.3)
       - HTTP Request Defaults
       - Cookie Manager
       + HTTP Request Z
```

Example:

`Thread Group A` on `192.168.1.1`

`Thread Group B` on `192.168.1.2`

`Thread Group C` on `192.168.1.3`

Anyone has any idea if something like this is possible on JMeter or not? Any suggestion or thoughts would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function combination

For example below setup will mean that the `HTTP Request 1` will be executed only on machine with IP address of `192.168.1.1` and `HTTP Request 2` will be run on all machines:

[image]

If you need text version of the condition expression:

```
${__jexl3("${__machineIP()}" == "192.168.1.1",)}
```

however you should be able to easily generate you own one using [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)